# WPF Binding to Xml; how to extract selected XmlElement and cast to Object

Tags: wpf, xml, serialization, combobox

I have a WPF ComboBox bound to an Xml file and XmlDataProvider

```
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="980"
          Canvas.Top="16"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          FontSize="45"
          Height="76"
          SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged"
          Padding="10"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Sites}, XPath=Site}"
          Name="comboBox1"
          Style="{DynamicResource InfoKioskLargeStyledDropDown}"
          Width="600" />
```

My XML Looks as so:

```
<Site>
    <Name>Campus Pride</Name>    
    <Url>CampusPride</Url>
    <SlideCount>10</SlideCount>
</Site>
```

I then have an object matched up matching my XML:

```
public class Site
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
   public int SlideCount { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is on ComboBox selection changed, retrieve the object in SelectedItem and cast it to an object of type Site. The problem is that the combobox1.SelectedItem property is an XmlElement. Is there a quick way to convert my XmlElement to a Site object, or do I have to invoke a serializer and do it manually?

Comment: Since it's just 3 fields, I'd just use Linq-to-XML and add a constructor to the `Site` class that takes an `XElement` and does the conversion.

Comment: Can I do that? I was under the assumption that by using an XmlDataProvider and binding the datasource to the combobox that I'd always get an XmlElement in the SelectedItem property, not an XElement.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  See here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165615.aspx

Comment: The other issue with this approach ( I used a constructor like you said) is that I need to pass a copy of the object Site to a new WPF Page so that the page can load the selected value in its own dropdown (say, combobox2). The problem with this approach is that I cannot do something like combobox2.SelectedItem = mySiteObject. ... Assuming combobox2 is bound to the same XML list.

Comment: Ah right ... but you should be able to use an `IValueConverter` for that, no?

Comment: I don't know, really. I'm pretty new to WPF. Can you maybe show me some sample code? Sorry,apologize for the newness.